# Remove menu item from display

Tags: 6, routes

How can I programatically remove/hide a menu item when the menu is displayed?

Comment: I just went through that problem, and i ended abandoning taxonomy menu to make a custom menu based on the current language. It will probably be faster than trying to make the module work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you can use `theme_menu_item_link()` function to your template.php of your theme.

This is an example that I have tested (in this example Garland is the theme used, so you must replace the name of the function with the respective name):

Here is the example menu:

[image: screenshot]

This is the function to remove the items:

```
function garland_menu_item_link($link) {
  if (empty($link['localized_options'])) {
    $link['localized_options'] = array();
  }
  if ($link['title'] != 'item 1') {
    $link['localized_options'] += array('html' => TRUE);
    return l('<span>' . $link['title'] . '</span>', $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
  }
  else {
    unset($link);
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Please note that I have added `if($link['title'] != 'item 1'){..` to detect the menu item, and remove it (with `unset($link)`).

This is the code for changing the text:

```
function garland_menu_item_link($link) {
  if (empty($link['localized_options'])) {
    $link['localized_options'] = array();
  }
  if ($link['title'] == 'item 1') {
    $link['title'] = 'new text';
  }

  $link['localized_options'] += array('html' => TRUE);
  return l('<span>' . $link['title'] . '</span>', $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Remember to clear the cache to see the changes.

I found these other resources related with [theme_menu_item_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item_link/6): http://drupal.org/node/245156, http://drupal.org/node/249864, http://drupal.org/node/417482.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to add that for filtering links by language just use: $link['options']['langcode'] == $language->language

Answer (score 1):

Here you have my implementation. I added the return line into the last `else`, and check for a specific role.

```
function batuka_menu_item_link($link) {
  global $user;
  if (in_array("club member", $user->roles)) {
    if (empty($link['localized_options'])) {
      $link['localized_options'] = array();
    }
    if ($link['title'] != 'Instructor Profile') {
      $link['localized_options'] += array('html'=>true);
      return l('<span>'.$link['title'].'</span>', $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
    }
    else {
      unset($link);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```